# Unable to write to file in"w" mode (IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'items.csv')

Tags: python

I have a python script which calls a bunch of other python scripts via `subprocess`.
One of these scripts has the following line:

```
items = open("items.csv","w")
```

I also tried:

```
path = os.getcwd()
items = open("%s/items.csv","w") %path
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'items.csv'
```

If I am using the file in "w" mode, it should get created if it doesn't exist. Then why am I getting this error.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Also tried using `items = open("%s/items.csv" % path,"w")`. But getting the same error again

**EDIT2:** The calling script:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex
import fileinput
import os

cmd = "python2 convert.py ebay.csv ebay.xml"
arg = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(arg)
p.wait()

cmd1 = "python2 convert.py all_products.csv all_products.xml"
arg1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(arg1)
p1.wait()

ebay = open("ebay.xml")
voylla = open("all_products.xml")

for line in fileinput.input("ebay.xml", inplace=True):
    print(line.replace("&", "and"))

for line in fileinput.input("all_products.xml", inplace=True):
    print(line.replace("&", "and"))

path = os.getcwd()
print path
cmd2 = "python2 compare.py ebay.xml all_products.xml"
arg2 = shlex.split(cmd2)
print cmd2
p2 = subprocess.Popen(arg2)
p2.wait()

cmd4 = "python2 convert.py items.csv items.xml"
arg4 = shlex.split(cmd4)
p4 = subprocess.Popen(arg4)
p4.wait()

#cmd4 = "python2 ReviseItem.py"
#arg4 = shlex.split(cmd4)
#p4 = subprocess.Popen(arg4)
#p4.wait()
```

compare.py:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import os

#sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
ebay = sys.argv[1]
voylla = sys.argv[2]

tree = ET.parse(ebay)
root = tree.getroot()

tree1 = ET.parse(voylla)
root1 = tree1.getroot()

path = os.getcwd()

items = open("%s/items.csv" % path,"w")
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `items = open('items.csv','w')`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : This was the first thing I tried, but this gives the same error

Comment: Are all the scripts in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here, since you are using subprocess in Python 2.7 to direct other python processes, is that the file will get locked for whatever process first attempts to create and write to the file. From the documentation:

```
Popen.wait()
Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process 
generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to 
accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.
```

Another issue to be aware of: you are using the "w" permission with `open`, which means all previous output will be overwritten. You would do better to open the file in a master process, create and close it, then use the "a" permission with open to append to the file for each process sequentially.

Also note that a data stream from a process is not actually written to the file until the file is closed.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding a link does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to open the file `'%s/items.csv'`, then apply the `% path` to the *return value of `open()`.

Move the string formatting to the string:

```
items = open("%s/items.csv" % path, "w")
```

However, you should use the [`os.path` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to handle path manipulation:

```
items = open(os.path.join(path, 'items.csv'), 'w')
```

or, in this case, use `os.path.abspath` instead, as it'll use `os.getcwd()` for you for relative paths:

```
items = open(os.path.abspath('items.csv'), 'w')
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error on using `items = open("%s/items.csv" % path,"w")`

Comment: @nish: it is still possible that you don't have write permission in the current working directory, or that your current working directory was deleted, or that your actual code is doing something different from what your post shows.

Comment: @nish: It could also be that on specific platforms `os.getcwd()` returns a path with a path delimiter at the end, and using string interpolation then can result in an invalid path. Use `os.path.abspath()` instead.

Comment: If I execute the script that contains this code separately, it works just fine.

Comment: @nish: Exactly, so **something else** in your code is contributing to the problem. Without seeing your code that's very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @nish: ah, it could be `subprocess` sets the current working directory to something that might not work. But why use `subprocess` here **at all**? Why not just import the Python code?

Comment: My xml files were not correct. Thats why I was getting this error. Resolved now